# Tab Detection using Android While Swapping between the Different Tabs (Sliding/Swip Tabs)?

Tags: android, tabs

how we can detect that we are in which tab using Android Sliding/Swip Tab ?

Below is sample Code which i am using:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        View rootView;
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    int currentView = args.getInt(SyncStateContract.Constants.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)-2;

    if(currentView == 0){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictureview,container, false);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(rootView.getContext()));
    }else if(currentView == 1){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictureview, container, false);
    }else {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictureview, container, false);
    }
    return rootView;
 }
```

Once i Place the Above code, i face one error **ARG_SECTION_NUMBER**

I have around 7 Tabs but i don't know how i can detect the while i am swaping between the Different Tabs. I am trying to implement Tabs something like **PlayStore**.

I follow this Link to build the Tabs:
           https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `setOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener)`
 method of PagerSlidingTabStrip
like this tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);
in page chage listener you have to implement onPageChagend() method that gives position of current page

Comment: **@Narendra** how about `View rootView;
  Bundle args = getArguments();
  int currentView = args.getInt(SyncStateContract.Constants.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)-2;

  if(currentView == 0){
   rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictureview,container, false);
   GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
   gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(rootView.getContext()));
  }else if(currentView == 1){
   rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictureview, container, false);
  }else {
   rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictureview, container, false);
  }

  return rootView;`

Comment: **@Narendra** can you implement under **onCreateView** function.

Comment: Can you place this code in your ans and well format it so that i can understand it